# Creating relationship classes

Tags: arccatalog, relationship-class, feature-dataset

I am trying to create relationship classes in a Feature Dataset. The Relationship Class created successfully, I want when I update a record in the Origin table the Destination's would be updated, but it didn't.

Any solution OR procedure?

Comment: I think this question needs more work to indicate what has been tried, and whether http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004t00000006000000.htm has been read, because that online help mentions various limitations.  Also, I would recommend avoiding use of abbreviations like FD and RC because your question will be more readable when they are written out in full.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update records based on edits to the origin, there are several ways to do it. What it boils down is to listen to the [Relationship Class events](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/COM/ExtendAO/ClassExtensionsAndRelClasses.htm) and to update accordingly. That is one way to do it. Another one is to do it as an [Editor Extension](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000391000000).